# How to get Age, income, education etc... data from census data

Tags: r

Use the `acs` package in R to query the census API and read in demographic variables for each zip code in the dataset. Try variables pertaining
to age, income, education, etc, you should use at least 20 variables.
Don't worry about the API Key I already have that and it is working
What I need is how to extract those from census data.
I have tried this

```
{zc <- get_acs(geography = "zcta", variables = "B19013_001")
print(zc)}
```

I got some data but I don't know what to do with it
Can anyone please help with this?

Comment: What is the output of str(zc) ?

Comment: Here is output for str(zc)

Comment: str(zc)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 33120 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ GEOID   : chr  "00601" "00602" "00603" "00606" ...
 $ NAME    : chr  "ZCTA5 00601" "ZCTA5 00602" "ZCTA5 00603" "ZCTA5 00606" ...
 $ variable: chr  "B19013_001" "B19013_001" "B19013_001" "B19013_001" ...
 $ estimate: num  13092 16358 16603 12832 19309 ...
 $ moe     : num  1049 1082 963 2393 1555 ...

Comment: Why am I getting *"No documentation for ‘get_acs’ in specified packages and libraries:
you could try ‘??get_acs’"*? Even after reinstalling the package.

Comment: https://walkerke.github.io/tidycensus/reference/get_acs.html

Comment: So that's package `tidycensus`, not package `acs`.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with the `acs` package, but I think you need to supply the call to `get_acs` with the names of the variables you want to get.

Because right now your response data.frame consists of `GEOID`, `NAME`, `variable`, `estimate` and `moe`. This is a data.frame in long form, meaning all the variables are listed in the column `variable` with their corresponding values in the columns `estimat` and `moe`...

Accordingly, `variable` seems to have only one value, "B19013_001", the name you specified in your call to `get_acs`.

What is the output of

```
zc2 <- get_acs(geography = "zcta", variables = c("age", "income")
names(zc2)
```

(assuming "age" and "income" are valid variable names)

Comment: Here is the output and there is no age, income or education in the output of the data.

Comment: # A tibble: 33,120 x 5
   GEOID NAME        variable   estimate   moe
   <chr> <chr>       <chr>         <dbl> <dbl>
 1 00601 ZCTA5 00601 B19013_001    13092  1049
 2 00602 ZCTA5 00602 B19013_001    16358  1082
 3 00603 ZCTA5 00603 B19013_001    16603   963
 4 00606 ZCTA5 00606 B19013_001    12832  2393
 5 00610 ZCTA5 00610 B19013_001    19309  1555
 6 00612 ZCTA5 00612 B19013_001    18171   944
 7 00616 ZCTA5 00616 B19013_001    16018  2211
 8 00617 ZCTA5 00617 B19013_001    16735  1795
 9 00622 ZCTA5 00622 B19013_001    15206  1774
10 00623 ZCTA5 00623 B19013_001    16280  1084

Comment: Thats strange... why are there still values for 'B19013_001' shown?? 

What does `?get_acs` say about the parameter 'variables'?

Comment: Yeah, that is the challenge that I am facing right now

Comment: I just did this {zc0 <- get_acs(geography = "zcta", variables = c(age = "B19013_001"))} and it is working because i got a data with the age column

Comment: What does ?get_acs say about the parameter 'variables'?